# Can't access localhost in LAMP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, moodle

First of all, I'm beginner at this, so don't be too harsh.
Yesterday, I wanted to make Linux Server. Installed LAMP, PhpMyAdmin. Man the websites IP static. I installed moodle on my website server. Then I closed VirtualBox and went to sleep.
Today when I runned my server and tried to access /phpmyadmin or (ipaddress)/moodle it says that webpage isn't available. Does this mean I have to do everything from the scratch again?
I'd appreciate any help.

I tried command sudo service apache2 start , but nothing changes.

Comment: may i know which os and server are you using?

Comment: did u start lampp??`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`.

Comment: Linux Server (Ubuntu)

Comment: are you running apache? maybe something in the configuration is wrong. But this is not the right place for this kind of question anyway.

Comment: You should ask this kind of questions in Server Fault (http://serverfault.com)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site askubuntu.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in Terminal:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**OR**

```
sudo restart apache2
```

Try the Answer on this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Comment: I get a weird messege " The Aliase directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
Apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to sppress this message''

Comment: Does that post solved your problem?

Comment: Now I get error ''The Alias directive in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf at line 3 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias."

Comment: The contents of apache.conf are already being loaded by phpmyadmin.conf located in /etc/apache2/conf.d which means that you can remove the following line from your apache2.conf file.


INCLUDE /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Hope this helps!

Comment: Waqas Shahid Thanks, that helped. Now doing 'restart' command I have no errors, but that doesn't change the fact, that if I try to access 'localhost' I see blank page and using the IP add (I used yday - which worked) now doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried accessing webpage & phpmyadmin through 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, same thing happens, just a blank page.

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to help because it becomes unclear to me now...

Comment: Is there some command to just delete all Apache/Moodle ect. files and start with clean Server from the scratch? Or the best way is to page new server?

Comment: Check this uninstalling steps on this link:
https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Installation_FAQ#How_do_I_uninstall_Moodle.3F

Comment: pluse-uno for technical support ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of basic troubleshooting steps to take here.

You mentioned "localhost" in your question, but this doesn't sound like the local host; if you're connecting to your guest machine from the host machine then both machines will treat it as a networking connection (because it is networking). How that networking is configured will depend on your VirtualBox configuration.

Are you sure the virtual machine is running, the IP address is assigned, and networking is, well, working? Try pinging the virtual/guest machine from the host machine. After pausing and resuming, one of my Debian machines used to always pick up a DHCP address on the host-networking adapter despite being set to a static address in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Look at `ifconfig` to verify the IP address listed is what you expect.

Are you sure Apache is running? Try accessing it from within the guest machine on http://localhost -- by telnet to port 80, command-line tool, or full-on web browser.

Are other services working? Try to connect remotely to whatever you have running: SSH, FTP, IMAP, MySQL, NTP -- try to connect and see if the problem is the network or the service.